# How to skip file in sed if it contains regex?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, text, newlines

I currently use the following [simplified command](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/0c3de26649bb1eee6813e7c8905b04c7e0045e00) to *remove trailing whitespace* and *add a newline at end of file* where needed:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/;$a\' {} \+
```

As you'll quickly see, this has two problems: It will change *binary files* and it will add a newline to the end of files with *␍␊ line separators*. These modifications are easy to undo or skip when committing in `git gui` or the like, but I'd like to minimize* the amount of reverting. To that end:

**Is there a way to skip the *whole* file if *any* line matches a regex in `sed`?**

* I'm aware that there might be binary files without ␀ characters, and there could be files with deliberately mixed newlines or ␀s. But I'm looking for the solution which requires the minimal human intervention. I *could* conceivably list all the file extensions that I'd like to operate on, but it would be a very long list which would have to be constantly reviewed, and because of name clashes it would still be possible that binary files slip through.

Complicated [workaround](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/c917321cd08846880258604690f5cff91ed35838):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    if [[ "$(file -bs --mime-type -- "$REPLY")" = text/* ]]
    then
        sed -i -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/;$a\' -- "$REPLY"
    else
        echo "Skipping $REPLY" >&2
    fi
done 9< <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Comment: Would you be ok with a `git`-only solution that trusts `git`'s view of what is a binary file and what is not?

Comment: If you can use Perl, it has a `-T` test that determines if the file is "an ASCII text file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trust `git`'s point of view on what is a binary file or not, you can use `git grep` to get a list of non-binary files. Assuming `t.cpp` is a text file, and `ls` is a binary, both checked in:

```
$ ls
t.cpp ls
$ git grep -I --name-only -e ''
t.cpp
```

The `-I` option means:

> `-I`
>      Don't match the pattern in binary files.

To combine that with your `sed` expression:

```
$ git grep -I --name-only -z -e '' | \
       xargs -0 sed -i.bk -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/;$a\'
```

(`-z` / `xargs -0` to help with strange filenames.)

Check out the `git grep` man page for other useful options - `--no-index` or `--cached` could help depending on exactly what set of files you want to operate on.

Comment: Neat! Note that it skips files of type "`Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`".

Comment: Well, yeah, that's why there's the "trust git's point of view" disclaimer :) Note that I'm not sure your sed expression would work on UTF-16 (doesn't on my machine here, but I guess there could be ways/settings to make it work).

Comment: Sure, that wasn't meant as a complaint, just FYI. After all, UTF-16 is *really* rare these days.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to skip the whole file if any line matches a regex in sed?

Yes, there is.

```
# test case for skipping file if a sed regex match succeeds

echo 'Hello, world!' > hello_world.txt
cat hello_world.txt
ls -li hello_world.txt

sed -i -e '/.*Hello.*/{q;}; s/world/WORLD/g' hello_world.txt # skips file
sed -i -e '/.*HeLLo.*/{q;}; s/world/WORLD/g' hello_world.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl script that iterates over its arguments (which must be file names) and appends a newline to every file that doesn't end in a newline. Files containing a null byte are skipped. Files that already end in a newline are unmodified. Files that contain a CR get CRLF appended, others get just LF. Untested.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
    open F, "<", $f or die;
    my $last = undef;
    my $cr = 0;
    while (<>) {if (/\0/) {undef $last; break} $last = $_; ++$cr if /\r$/}
    close F;
    if (defined $last && $last !~ /\n\Z/) {
        open F, ">>", $f or die;
        print($cr ? "\r\n" : "\n");
        close F or die;
    }
}
```