# Is there a way to detect null bytes (␀, NUL, \0) in sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Related to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36233/how-to-skip-file-in-sed-if-it-contains-regex), in order to fuzzily detect binary files, is there a way to detect ␀ bytes in `sed`?

Comment: In GNU sed, yes, but note that on many unices, text utilities are not capable of handling null bytes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Example:

Prove I'm sending a NUL byte, followed by a newline:

```
$ echo -e \\0 | hexdump -C
00000000  00 0a                                             |..|
00000002
```

Now I change the NUL byte to an `!` exclamation mark:

```
$ echo -e \\0 | sed 's/\x00/!/' | hexdump -C
00000000  21 0a                                             |!.|
```

So the trick is using `\x00` as NUL-byte.

Comment: You can `echo -ne \\0` to avoid a newline.

Comment: Replace `hexdump -C` with `uniname -bcepu` to see which character it dumps.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `\x` is a non-standard `sed` extension, but [GNU `sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#index-g_t_0040acronym_007bGNU_007d-extensions_002c-special-escapes-222) does provide it.

Comment: It should be also mentioned, that `echo -e` is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). `printf` is much more compatible.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the pattern `\x00` matches to the null byte.

Example:

```
$ printf "\0\n\0\n" > file
$ sed -e 's/\x00/test/' -i file
$ cat file
test
test
$
```

Comment: @l0b0: The reason, why it worked for me, was that I used zsh. According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), it replaces `\0` by the zero byte. This replacement is not necessary ("shall be supported"), and actually bash does not support it directly. For it, you need to use `echo -e`. I replace `echo` with with `printf` in my answer which seems to be more compatible...